# Need a LVDS controller (with HDMI) for 1920x720 LCD display

Tags: displays

I have a LCD panel with an uncommon resolution of 1920x720 (8:3 aspect). Now, I need a LVDS controller board to use it with a HDMI connection.

Model Number: S123WU01

[Basic specs](http://www.panelook.com/S123WU01_CDTECH_12.3_LCM_overview_26051.html)

[Datasheet](http://www.mediafire.com/view/29w75kh52m7sbs2/S123WU01.pdf)

What LVDS controller is recommended?

Answer (score 0):

This LVDS driver board [from ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/HDMI-DVI-VGA-Driver-LVDS-Inverter-Kit-Convert-a-Bare-Laptop-LCD-into-Monitor-/111115624120?hash=item19df01deb8:g:1~sAAOxyrUZRymfp) has a quoted max resolution of 2048X1152.

It says in the description that when you order the board, you need to supply the model number of your LCD panel so they can give you the correct kit.